# Navigation bar showing, but buttons and title do not show

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]I have a navigation controller connected with a segue to my viewcontroller and it shows that the navigation bar is there but no buttons are appearing and no title is appearing. I tried changing the color of the navbar to black in xcode it changed but when I go into simulator it is still white. 
In order to present this viewcontroller, when login button is tapped..

```
  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "loggedIn") != nil {
            print("User will stay logged in")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatRoom", sender: self)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: did you set title & backbutton? i haven't saw that in your screenshot of storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**
Your segue should connect from login vc to navigation controller like this:
[image: expected segue]

**original**
To set title of viewcontroller having navigation controller:
[image: set navigation bar title]

To manually set backbutton of rootviewcontroller of navigation controller:
(rootcontroller would not auto generate back button)
[image: set back button]

Comment: Sorry about that, I removed the buttons before I took the screen shot, I will re do it

Comment: @KimRiegel Would you also post some code how you initiate view controller?

Comment: @KimRiegel May I see your segue on your storyboard? The segue should be connected to navigation controller but not the view controller you want to display

Comment: Im confused... Where do I connect the segue then?

Comment: How do you implement your segue `chatRoom`??

Comment: Very happy to help you. :)